# sql query help to select overriden value

Tags: t-sql

For the same ColA value, say 'A' if ColB value is overridden (read: has some value) - default being blank, then I want to pick that row's ColVal (read: overridden description) else the default rows' ColVal value.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [ColA]   [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [ColB]   [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [ColVal] [varchar](50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [pkTestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ColA] ASC,
        [ColB] ASC
    )
)

INSERT INTO TestTable([ColA], [ColB], [ColVal])
VALUES ('A', N' ', N'A Description')

INSERT INTO TestTable([ColA], [ColB], [ColVal])
VALUES ('A', N'override', N'Overridden Description for A')

INSERT INTO TestTable([ColA], [ColB], [ColVal])
VALUES ('B', N' ', N'B Description')
```

The below is my attempt and it doesn't look right. First query is returning two rows. I just want the one with 'Overridden Description for A'

```
DECLARE @colAParam varchar(10) = 'A'

SELECT colval FROM TestTable
WHERE ColB = coalesce(Nullif(ColB, N' '), ColB) AND colA = @colAParam

-- Expected Outcome : 'Overridden Description for A'

Set @colAParam = 'B'
SELECT colval FROM TestTable
WHERE ColB = coalesce(Nullif(ColB, N' '), ColB) AND colA = @colAParam

-- Expected Outcome : 'B Description'
```

This works but could someone help me with a better and terse syntax please?

```
DECLARE @colAParam varchar(10) = 'A'

if exists(select * from TestTable where nullif(ColB, N' ') is not null and colA = @colAParam)
begin
    select colval from TestTable where nullif(ColB, N' ') is not null and colA = @colAParam
end
else
begin
    select colVal from TestTable where nullif(ColB, N' ') is null and 
colA = @colAParam
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
select x.ColA, x2.ColVal from  
(
   (select t.ColA from dbo.TestTable t group by t.ColA) x   
   cross apply (select top 1 t2.ColVal from dbo.TestTable t2 where t2.ColA = x.ColA order by nullif(t2.ColB, N' ') desc) x2 
)
```

Returns a row for each ColA group.
The derived table "x", is used to get one row for each ColA group.
Then each row is applied to derived table "x2", which tries to get the appropriate ColVal for each group.

If you just want the result for one specific group, then can do something like:

```
DECLARE @colAParam varchar(10) = 'A'
select top 1 t2.ColVal from dbo.TestTable t2 where t2.ColA = @colAParam order by nullif(t2.ColB, N' ') desc
```